# Sort order for ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy in table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord

I want to set up sort order for active record collection proxy in table.
It should be sorted by number of available rooms (from highest to lowest).
The trick is that `@rooms.reserved` is a boolean and to calculate quantity of free/reserved rooms I have to use helper method to avoid record collection proxy errors. I get proper results, but I need to sort table by number of available rooms.

I have two models: Room and Hotel.

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel, optional: true # avoiding rails 5.2 belongs_to error 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel
end
```

and

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms
end
```

I have table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Rooms count</th>
    <th>Rooms status: in reserve || free</th>    
  </tr>

  <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= hotel.name %></td>
      <td><%= hotel.rooms_count %></td>
      <td><%= rooms_reservation_status(hotel.rooms) %></td>  <!-- rooms_reservation_status helper method in application_helper.rb -->      
      <td ><%= link_to 'Show', hotel_path(hotel) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', hotel, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Helper method

```
# rooms_reservation_status iterates throught ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy 
# and calculates the sum of free rooms aswell as a sum of reserved rooms
  def rooms_reservation_status(rooms)
    reserved = 0
    free     = 0
    rooms.each do |r|
      r.reserved == true ? reserved+=1 : free+=1
    end
    "#{reserved} || #{free}"
  end
```

Active Record table for rooms:

```
class CreateRooms < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :rooms do |t|
      t.boolean :reserved, :default => false
      t.belongs_to :hotel, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Implement a join, and a where clause and then group by and count. All can be done in Active record. Also which DB are you using?

Comment: @user1735921 I've never used this technique before. I use default SQLite.

Comment: `@hotels = Hotel.select('count(*) as free_rooms').joins(:rooms).group('rooms.id').order('free_rooms DESC')` and then access the rooms by hotel.free_rooms

Comment: @user1735921 I believe I do something wrong. Can you give a little bit wider answer, thanks. The best way is not just solve the issue but understand solving as well.

Comment: sorry I don't know much, can't help you more than this. i am trying my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a class method on the `Room` model in order to return for a given collection the number of free rooms and reserved rooms:

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :hotel

  def self.reserved_count
    where(reserved: true).count
  end

  def self.free_count
    where(reserved: false).count
  end
end
```

Once you have implemented, you can call it from the relationship declared in `Hotel` model:

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rooms

  def reserved_rooms
    rooms.reserved_count
  end

  def free_rooms
    rooms.free_count
  end
end
```

Your view will look finally like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Rooms count</th>
    <th>Rooms status: in reserved || free</th>    
  </tr>

  <% @hotels.each do |hotel| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= hotel.name %></td>
      <td><%= hotel.rooms_count %></td>
      <td><%= "#{hotel.reserved_rooms} || #{hotel.free_rooms}" %></td>      
      <td ><%= link_to 'Show', hotel_path(hotel) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', hotel, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

#### Sorting the Hotels in your controller

In your controller make sure that you [eager load](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/improving-the-performance-of-your-rails-app-with-eager-loading--cms-25018) `Rooms` for `Hotel`:

```
@hotels = Hotel.includes(:rooms).sort_by { |h| h.free_rooms.to_i }.reverse
```

You could eventually implement it as `Hotel.includes(:rooms).sort_by(&:free_rooms).reverse`.

In this way you won't need any join or helper.

Regarding your comment, `free_rooms` is implemented as an instance method (e.g. `Hotel.first.free_rooms`), so it will not be available for an `ActiveRecord_Relation` (e.g. `Hotel.all.free_rooms`)

Comment: Your code only re factor mine. It is still undefined method `free_rooms' for #<Hotel::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f2809db69c8> when I try to sort them through controller. And this is correct behavior because I cant get straight access to free_rooms. I have access only to ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation. Unfortunately  I can't properly sort ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation. Thats the issue.

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov did this update answer to your original question?